# Can Time Manager ignore/skip time when there is no data?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I have several months of data where it is only between 8am and 5pm mon-fri.  When I export .png images in time manager it includes the time in between, eg 5pm-8am and sat-sun.  Is there a way for it to ignore those times and only export the data?

Comment: I think at the moment, the plugin only allows you to ignore features which contain empty geometries, not certain times. I understand it would be too tedious to constantly change the _Start_ and _End_ times for all those days and then export the images. You could post a [feature request](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/) and hope it will come in a future version =)

Comment: I thought so.  I'm doing one hour intervals and over a 12 week period that equates to 480 images of movement verses 1636 static or 77% of the time nothing is happening.  If it was possible I could do 20 minute intervals and have a better video with out sacrificing length.  I'll try a feature request.

Comment: Do you need to display the date/time on your animation through the plugin? If not, you can use unix timestamps as a substitute for frame numbers, or for allocating sequential numbers to successive working hours. Would need some python code, though

Comment: Date/time isn't necessary however I'm not versed in python coding.

Answer (score 1):

No that's currently not possible.

If you are able to provide a pull request to add the feature (and accompanying tests), please feel free to do so.